# Update newest row of database with same column value

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a table like below:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| year     |  period     |  publish_date |  status   |
-----------|-------------|---------------|-----------|
|  2020    |     03      |  datetime_obj |     0     |
|  2020    |     03      |  ...          |     0     |
|  2020    |     03      |  ...          |     0     |
|  2020    |     03      |  ...          |     0     |
|  2020    |     04      |  ...          |     0     |
|  2020    |     04      |  ...          |     0     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

and i want update status for newest publish date in any year and period group but i dont have any idea for this

for example :
select all rows for year 2020 with period 03 and then update stauts of newest publish_date to 1 and then do same operation for year 2020 with period 04 until the end ...
i want use this in django so please explain with pythonic way or sql query

this is my django model:

```
class Balance_Sheet(models.Model):
    ...
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    period = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    ...
```

thank you so much

Comment: Where is your django model for this table?

Comment: @roganjosh i add my django model in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work in mysql

```
UPDATE Balance_Sheet b
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(publish_date) LastDate, year, period FROM bs GROUP BY year, period) C
    ON C.LastDate = b.publish_date and C.period = b.period and C.year = b.year
SET b.status = 1
where C.LastDate = b.publish_date and C.period = b.period and C.year = b.year
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with django but the sql for it would look like this. Since you already have balance sheet table. You only need the update part.

```
WITH balance_sheet(id ,yearmonth , publish_date, status)
AS (SELECT 1, '202003',  '2020-03-10' , 0   UNION 
    SELECT 2, '202003',  '2020-03-15' , 0   UNION
    SELECT 3, '202004',  '2020-04-20' , 0   UNION
    SELECT 4, '202004',  '2020-04-25' , 0
   )

UPDATE b
SET status = 1
FROM balance_sheet b
JOIN (Select *,RANK() OVER (partition by yearmonth ORDER BY publish_date desc) AS rnk 
from balance_sheet bal) b_latest ON b.id = b_latest.id
WHERE b_latest.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

One easy way out is to iterate over year/month applying filters:

```
years = {sheet.year for sheet in Balance_Sheet.objects.all()}

for year in years:
  year_months = {sheet.month for sheet in Balance_Sheet.objects.filter(year=year)}

  for month in year_months:
    object_to_update = Balance_Sheet.objects.filter(
      year=year,
      period=month
    ).order_by('-publish_date').first()

    object_to_update.status = 1
    object_to_update.save()
```

There might be more complex ORM functions to make this into a single query, but the code I wrote there (not tested) is going to work in most/all Django versions. Also, the amount of queries to database won't be massive since we are talking about year/month amounts.

**Solution 2**

In a postgres database you can try this:

```
Balance_Sheet.objects.all().order_by(
    'year', 'period', '-publish_date'
).distinct(
    'year', 'period'
).update(
    status=1
)
```

Note that this won't work in other databases such as MySQL. See the django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Comment: yes but this can be Big O problem. just my test data is 52,000 row!!!

Comment: @DanialEshghi Which django version and database are you using? These things might change between mysql and postgresql.

Comment: @DanialEshghi The operation you want to do sounds like a maintainance action. Running the code I wrote you let's say, once a day, is not problematic. Let's say you have publications for 50 or 100 years, each year will run 13 queries in the worst case. If you have to run this action constantly it might be convenient that you refactor your system to update the status field automatically when conditions meet.

Comment: yes database might change every things. before this problem i think every sql database are similar but with this problem i understand how many diffrence exist between them. thank you

Comment: about second comment: this opertation run hourly and i have another foreign key column `ref_id` belong to about 1000 row. this 52,000 row is just for 1 `ref_id` and 10 years in reality my data is about 30 years and more

Comment: i added a possible solution if you are using postgresql